the param of max_allowed_packet don't enffective in mysql
this is a insert sql demo of longblob, i have some questions. read the follow code for details
import java.sql.*;

public class InsertTestData2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://10.100.x.xx:xxxx/pipeace?characterEncoding=utf-8&useSSL=false";
        String username = "xxx";
        String password = "xxx";

        /**
         * this is my table desc
         *
         * mysql> desc my_pa_pkg;
         * +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
         * | Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
         * +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
         * | id    | varchar(33) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
         * | jar   | longblob    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
         * +-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
         * 2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
         *
         *
         * version of mysql
         *
         * mysql> select version();
         * +-----------+
         * | version() |
         * +-----------+
         * | 5.7.18    |
         * +-----------+
         * 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
         *
         * max_allowed_packet config , 50MB
         *
         * mysql> show VARIABLES like '%max_allowed_packet%';
         * +--------------------------+------------+
         * | Variable_name            | Value      |
         * +--------------------------+------------+
         * | max_allowed_packet       | 52428800   |
         * | slave_max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |
         * +--------------------------+------------+
         * 2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
         */

        String insertQuery = "INSERT INTO my_pa_pkg (id, jar) VALUES (?, ?)";

        try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
             PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(insertQuery)) {

            String id = "uuid_xxx";
            byte[] data = new byte[40140381]; // about 40MB
            statement.setString(1, id);
            statement.setBytes(2, data);
            int execute = statement.executeUpdate();
            System.out.println("Rows inserted: " + execute);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

this is result of debug, i don't understand  80,280,832 in result, because my byte array is 40140381, why is large than my define in this
 com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (80,280,832 > 52,428,800). You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:107)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:916)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1061)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1009)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1320)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:994)
    at InsertTestData2.main(InsertTestData2.java:37)

so, I start to read the source code of mysql jdbc, i found some code as follow
file: com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.AbstractValueEncoder#escapeBytesIfNeeded(byte[])
// source code
protected byte[] escapeBytesIfNeeded(byte[] x) {
        if (this.serverSession.isNoBackslashEscapesSet() || this.serverSession.getCharsetSettings().isMultibyteCharset(this.charEncoding.getValue())) {
            // I don't known the `(x.length * 2) + 3` , Can a professional engineer answer the question?
            // I found the reason for why of number 80,280,832 from this code. But I don't understand the reason for this design.
            // Send as hex
            ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream((x.length * 2) + 3);
            bOut.write('x');
            bOut.write('\'');
            StringUtils.hexEscapeBlock(x, x.length, (lowBits, highBits) -> {
                bOut.write(lowBits);
                bOut.write(highBits);
            });
            bOut.write('\'');
            return bOut.toByteArray();
        }
        // escape them
        ByteArrayOutputStream bOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream(x.length + 9);
        bOut.write('_');
        bOut.write('b');
        bOut.write('i');
        bOut.write('n');
        bOut.write('a');
        bOut.write('r');
        bOut.write('y');
        bOut.write('\'');
        StringUtils.escapeBytes(bOut, x);
        bOut.write('\'');
        return bOut.toByteArray();
    }

so,my maully question is the code new ByteArrayOutputStream((x.length * 2) + 3), this lead to  the param of max_allowed_packet don't enffective on the surface。Can a professional engineer answer the question？

Can you rephrase your question? I don't understand what "my maully question is the code new ByteArrayOutputStream((x.length * 2) + 3), this lead to the param of max_allowed_packet don't enffective on the surface" means.

One answer is that mysql sends a blob as a hex string, so each byte takes two characters, and so the packet is twice as big as the size of the BLOB in bytes. Was that your question?

@tgdavies , thank you very much , now ，I know the reason for (x.length * 2). addition，If this is the case, it will cause a conflict between the max_allowed_packet parameter and my blob file size, for example, my blob file is 40M, and the max_allowed_packet parameter is set to 50M, which will fail to insert, is this reasonable?

I'm still not certain what question you're asking. What do you mean by "reasonable" in this context. Please ask a clear question.

@tgdavies, thanks for your reply, As you said, mysql sends a blob in the form of a hexadecimal string, so it takes two characters per byte, and the packet is twice the size of the BLOB (in bytes), which in this design leads me to the wrong understanding that my file size is 80 MB (actually 40 MB), and I think it's not reasonable.

I still don't understand what you mean by "reasonable" and what your question is.

@tgdavies, Thank you for your patience to recover, i think byte convert to hex String is not suitable, becasuse it lead to the sendPacket increase twice, and my actual byte[] is smaller than max_allowed_packet of mysql server. As is conventional, the insert should succeed, but the actual insert fails (because the send packet is twice as large). it leads me to the wrong understanding that my byte[] size is 80 MB (actually 40 MB).
my questions: Why can't I send my original bytes directly, do I have to send them to hexadecimal?

Have a look at blobSendChunkSize https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-j-connp-props-blob-clob-processing.html Note that I think you need to use a PreparedStatement for that to work.
